# Is it possible to capture parameters with Google Mock (gmock)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

I am planning on using Google Mock. I need to capture an object reference so that I can subsequently call some methods from that object.

Does Google Mock have any capturing abilities? If not, what are the other choices for C++ unit testing? One choice would be to create my own mock class that captures the object.

I am looking for something similar to Java's [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/). Example (not real code):

```
Capture<MyObject> capture;
EXPECT_CALL(myInterface, access(capture));
instanceUnderTest.setAccessPoint(myInterface);
instanceUnderTest.run();
MyObject &capturedObject = capture.getValue();
EXPECT_EQ(ACCESS_IN_PROGRESS, capturedObject.getState());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a custom action to capture a method parameter by reference (there is a standard `SaveArg` action to capture one by value). But what you want can be achieved in a simpler fashion:

```
using testing::Property;
using testing::Eq;
EXPECT_CALL(myInterface,
            access(Property(&MyObject::getState, Eq(ACCESS_IN_PROGRESS))));
```